# JQuery animation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

An animation for a loading message is done by JQuery. When the page is about to be redirected to another page, the loading message is displayed. Here what the animation does is, increase the width of a `DIV` element.
`$('#loading').css({"width:":value});`

Above,'value' is increased through `setInnterval()`, My problem is, when the page is going to redirect to the other page(some time for 4 ,5 seconds) the animation doesn't happen. Any one let me know why this happen and how this can be avoided ?

Comment: Why didn't you post the `setInterval()` code?

Comment: What do you mean *when* the page is going to redirect?

Comment: Here is the setInterval  `setInterval(function(){$('#loading').css({"width:":value}); value +=10 },1000) `

Answer (score 1):

why not just use the inbuilt jQuery animate instead of your own `setInterval`?

```
$('#loading').animate({ width: finalValue });
```

you just need to tell it what you want the final width to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need show more detail of your code, basicly redirect may happens before the animation, you may watch the value, then when the value up to the maximum, do the redirect.

```
var value = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(value >= someValue){
        clearInterval(timer);
        location.href = 'someURL';
    }else{
        $('#loading').css('width', value++);
    }
});
```

haven't test yet.